# Can I convert those two LINQ Statement in a OneLiner (C#)

Tags: c#, linq

I have those statements who checks if I have all the answers in a Grid. Each row is identified by a ContextYID.

I would like to know if i can combine those LinQ query and convert it directly to a True/False Statement.

```
int nbRow = Answers.Where(a => a.FieldId == result.Id && a.FieldYId == fieldYAxi.Id)
                   .Select(a => a.ContextYId)
                   .Distinct()
                   .Count();

int nbAnswer = Answers.Count(a =>
a.FieldId == result.Id &&
a.FieldXId == fieldXAxi.Id &&
a.FieldYId == fieldYAxi.Id);

if (nbAnswer != nbRow)
    return false;
else
    return true;
```

Comment: What happens if `nbAnswer == nbRow`? Do you `return true`, or does something else happen? Are you looking for an answer that's simply `return [something]` or `if (something) return false`?

Comment: @TimS. Yeah in fact i return true if the number of rows match the number of answers

Comment: If *Each row is identified by a ContextYID*, I guess that means each row has a unique `ContextYId`, what's the point of `.Select(a => a.ContextYId).Distinct().Count()` instead of simply `Answers.Count(a => a.FieldId == result.Id ... )`?

Comment: My code works,  but I'm look for something to Optimize It!

Comment: Do you have some sample data you code share with expectations?  I have a feeling you could use `Aggregate` and do this as a single pass.

Comment: Years later, I came upon a comment you left in the code which pointed out to this question ;) Yeah there are still people working on code you worked on in 2013 ;) Turns out these LINQ queries could be removed altogether by checking a property at a higher scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is an improvement, because the `FieldId` and `FieldYID` only need to be compared once, and I simplified your return statements into one line.

```
var matchingAnswers = Answers.Where(a => a.FieldId == result.Id
                                      && a.FieldYId == fieldYAxi.Id).ToList();
int nbRow = matchingAnswers
                .Select(a => a.ContextYId)
                .Distinct()
                .Count();
int nbAnswer = matchingAnswers.Count(a => a.FieldXId == fieldXAxi.Id);
return nbAnswer == nbRow;
```

If you like, you can shorten this by merging the last few lines:

```
var matchingAnswers = Answers.Where(a => a.FieldId == result.Id
                                      && a.FieldYId == fieldYAxi.Id).ToList();
return matchingAnswers.Count(a => a.FieldXId == fieldXAxi.Id) ==
       matchingAnswers.Select(a => a.ContextYId).Distinct().Count();
```

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't equals work?

```
return Answers.Where(a => a.FieldId == result.Id && a.FieldYId == fieldYAxi.Id)
               .Select(a => a.ContextYId)
               .Distinct()
               .Count()
               .Equals(Answers.Count(a =>
                       a.FieldId == result.Id &&
                       a.FieldXId == fieldXAxi.Id &&
                       a.FieldYId == fieldYAxi.Id));
```

Comment: That's doing the Job! Thks.  For now it's the best Answer!

Comment: You should have a good read at @TimS' answer also, he seems to have put a bit more thought into it, I just mushed the two together :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work. Is there a particular reason you want to do this?

```
return Answers.Where(a => a.FieldId == result.Id && a.FieldYId == fieldYAxi.Id)
              .Select(a => a.ContextYId)
              .Distinct()
              .Count()
    == Answers.Count(a => a.FieldId  == result.Id 
                       && a.FieldXId == fieldXAxi.Id 
                       && a.FieldYId == fieldYAxi.Id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this is functionally equivalent to what are doing (but I do wonder what you're doing for the duplicate ContextYIds that satisfy nbAnswer multiple times):

```
var distinctContextYIds = new HashSet<int>();

return 0 == Answers.Where(a => a.FieldId == result.Id && a.FieldYId == fieldYAxi.Id)
    .Aggregate(0, (tally, answer) =>
    {
        if (distinctContextYIds.Add(answer.ContextYId))
            tally += 1;

        if (answer.FieldXId == fieldXAxi.Id)
            tally -= 1;

        return tally;
    });
```